# How To Integrate CKFinder To TinyMCE4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, tinymce, ckfinder

Sorry for my bad english. I tried to explain the problems I encountered.
I'm using asp.net MVC5.
I want to integrate the ckfinder to tinymce4.
This code works, but only successful in one area. How can I integrate all areas.

```js
tinymce.init({
            ...
            file_browser_callback: function() {
                var finder = new CKFinder();
                finder.selectActionFunction = SetFileField;
                finder.popup();}
             ...
       
        });
function SetFileField(fileUrl) {
            jQuery('#mceu_47-inp').val(fileUrl);
        }
```

Comment: this seems to be be very specific  (adresses only one ui element): jQuery('#mceu_47-inp')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use code bellow

```
tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea#desc',
     toolbar_items_size: 'small',
     menubar: false,
     plugins: [],
    toolbar1: "",
    image_advtab: true,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host : false,
    file_browser_callback: openKCFinder,
    file_browser_callback_types: 'file image media'

});

function openKCFinder(field_name, url, type, win) {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file: '/kcfinder/ckfinder.html',//path to your ckfinder
        title: 'KCFinder',
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        resizable: "yes",
        inline: true,
        close_previous: "no",
        popup_css: false
    }, {
        window: win,
        input: field_name
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could put a line of two of explanation